# Remove all ACL from user access of content using IBM WCM API

Tags: ibm-wcm

Is there a way to remove/reset user access from content item when we restart workflow of that content item using ibm WCM API?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use custom work flow actions to reset it.  Once you restart the work flow, the content will take the access from the current work flow stage.
Avoid giving administrator defined privileges to work flow content:
keep all privileges as work flow defined

you can use API's to rest access for content c as below

```
c.removeMembersForAccess(Access.EDITOR, c.getMembersForAccess(Access.EDITOR));
```